# Location of document root of public html in Centos

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I am following installation steps for Drupal and I am unable to follow one of the steps given below.

> Move the contents of  the drupal-x.x directory into a directory within
>   your **web server's document root** or **public HTML directory** (ensure that
>   the .htaccess file, a hidden file, is successfully moved into the
>   destination directory as well.

I am not sure where **web server's document root** or **public HTML directory** are located in my Centos machine. I tried finding public_html directory in my Centos machine using

I tried the following:

`sudo find / -name public_html -type d` - it did not return anything.

`sudo  find / -name .htaccess` - it did not return anything except the .htaccess file from the drupal download

Apache is installed though -

```
httpd -v: (returned the following on terminal)
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built: May 23 2014 14:34:17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is `/var/www/html` but this can be set to any directory in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks for the response! /var/www/html folder is empty in my case

Comment: could you please tell me which line or where to edit in httpd.conf? I found ServerRoot somewhere in the beginning of the file

Comment: found DocumentRoot set as "/var/www/html" is that one that should be changed or can be left as is and the drupal contents can be moved to that DocumentRoot location?

Comment: You can leave `DocumentRoot` as is and move your files there or set it to somewhere else. Your server, your choice.